# Sprite Animation Problem For Enemy

Tags: game-maker

I have a problem regarding the attack animation for the enemy. The problem is that the attack animation sprite stops at the first index.It doesn't play the animation.It stops at the first index. Why? Any suggestions.

Here is the code(It's in the step event)

```
if(distance_to_object(player)<10){

    hspeed = 0;
    vspeed =0;  
    enemy.x=enemy.x;
    enemy.y=enemy.y;   

    if(sprite_index == enemy_left){
        sprite_index=enemy_left_attack1;
    } 

    if(sprite_index == enemy_right){
        sprite_index=enemy_right_attack1;
    } 

     if(sprite_index == enemy_up){
        sprite_index=enemy_up_attack1;
    } 

     if(sprite_index == enemy_down){
        sprite_index=enemy_down_attack1;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `image_speed` after changing your sprite.

Like such:

```
if(sprite_index == enemy_up){
  sprite_index = enemy_up_attack1;
  image_speed = some_number_that_looks_good_to_you;
}
```

... or right before last bracket (`distance > 10` end bracket) to do it in one line instead of 4 lines...

hope it helps.